# How to get Ribbon to use IPs instead of hostnames

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix

I've created a Zuul server using the '@EnableZuulProxy' annotation. So I'm using Spring Cloud.

I can see it getting its info from Eureka and it is using Ribbon to executed requests. So far so good.

But it is using the hostnames from the Eureka data instead of the IP addresses. That is a problem for me since not all my hosts have their name in DNS.

I tried using 'ribbon.useIPAddrForServer=true' but I do not see a change in behavior.

I'm using 1.0.3.RELEASE at the moment.

Any thoughts on what I can do to resolve this?

Thanks.

Henry

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to use 'ribbon.UseIPAddrForServer=true'. Notice the capital 'U'.